# If $X$ is a right-continuous, discrete Markov process, then $\displaystyle\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\operatorname P_x\left[X_t=x\right]=1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be an at most countable Polish space and $\mathcal E$ be the discrete topology on $E$
- $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a discrete Markov process with values $(E,\mathcal E)$ and distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$

> **Claim**$\;\;\;$Let $$\operatorname p_t(x,y):=\operatorname P_x\left[X_t=y\right]\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E\text{ and }t\ge 0\;.$$ If $X$ is right-continuous, then $$\lim_{t\downarrow 0}p_t(x,x)=1\;.\tag 1$$

How can we prove the claim? I've tried the following: Let $$\tau:=\inf\left\{s>0:X_s\ne X_0\right\}$$ and $x\in E$. Clearly, since $\operatorname P_x$-almost surely $X_0=x$, $$\operatorname P_x\left[\tau>t\right]=\operatorname P_x\left[X_s=X_0\text{ for all }s\in (0,t]\right]\le p_t(x,x)\;\;\;\text{for all }t>0\;.\tag 2$$ Two questions:

1. How exactly does the right-continuity of $X$ imply $$\tau>0\;\;\;\operatorname P_x\text{-almost surely}\tag 3$$ for all $x\in E$?
2. Why can we conclude $(1)$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Comment: Well, under $P_x$, $[\tau=0]=[\lim\limits_{t\to0}X_t\ne x]$.

Comment: @Did Could you explain why this identity is true and why this is an answer to (1.) and/or (2.)?

Comment: Which inclusion is problematic to you?

Comment: @Did Well, $$\left\{\tau=0\right\}=\left\{\forall t>0:X_t\ne x\right\}\;.$$ If we assume, that $\mathcal E$ is the discrete topology (I'm not sure if you've done that or not), then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $$y\not\in U\;\;\;\text{for all }y\in E\setminus\left\{x\right\}\;,$$ So, $$\left\{\forall t>0:X_t\ne x\right\}=\left\{\forall t>0:X_t\not\in U\right\}=\left\{\lim_{t\downarrow 0}X_t\ne x\right\}\;.$$ That's what you meant, right?
[All set equations are assumed to be considered under $\operatorname P_x$]

Comment: @Did This leads to the same argument dafinguzman has used in his answer, right? Since $X$ is right-continuous, $$\operatorname P_x\left[\lim_{t\downarrow 0}X_t=x\right]=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\;,$$ right? [Besides: Does "right-continuity" of a Markov process really mean, that its paths are almost surely right-continuous **with respect to each $\operatorname P_x$**?]

Comment: Sorry but you pile bizarre statements upon bizarre statements so let me stay with the first one of the list: {τ=0}={∀t>0:Xt≠x}... Really? Actually, no (to know what {τ=0} corresponds to, please refer to my first comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof by contradiction:

Suppose that $p_t(x,x)$ does not converge to $1$ as $t\downarrow 0$ . Then there exist a sequence of times $t_n \downarrow 0$ and an $\epsilon >0$ such that $p_{t_n}(x,x)\le 1- \epsilon$ for all $n$.

Moreover, the latter implies, by taking complements, that $P_x(X_{t_n}\ne x) \ge \epsilon$ for all $n$. As the space is discrete, **I'll assume the discrete topology**, so that $X_{t_n}\ne x$ implies that $X_{t_n}$ lies outside the fixed neighborhood $V=\{x\}$ of $x$.

Now, by the reverse Fatou lemma, $$ \epsilon \le \limsup_n P_x(X_{t_n}\ne x) \le P_x(\limsup_n\{X_{t_n}\ne x\}) = P_x\{X_{t_n}\not \in V \text{ for infinitely many }t_n\},$$

and this implies that, with probability at least $\epsilon$, $X_{t_n}\overset{n}{\not \to} x$, contradicting the right continuity claim.

Comment: Why is $\displaystyle\limsup_n\operatorname P_x\left[X_{t_n}\ne x\right]=\varepsilon$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Sorry, my bad, that was meant to say $\ge \epsilon$. Then it is true because, by construction, all of the $t_{n}$ have that property.

Comment: Do we really need to introduce $V$? By the definition of convergence of a sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ agains $x_0$ in a topological space, it's sufficient to show, that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $$\forall N:\exists n>N:x_n\notin U\;.$$ Now, since $E$ is discrete, $\left\{x\right\}$ itself is an open neighborhood of $x$. Noting that $$\omega\in\limsup_n\left\{X_{t_n}\ne x\right\}\Leftrightarrow\forall N:\exists n\ge N:X_{t_n}(\omega)\not\in\left\{x\right\}\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{t_n}( \omega)\ne x\;,$$

Comment: the last implication should immediately yield $$\operatorname P_x\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{t_n}\ne x\right]\ge\operatorname P_x\left[\limsup_n\left\{X_{t_n}\ne x\right\}\right]\ge\varepsilon\;,$$ which is, as you've pointed out, a contradiction to $t_n\downarrow 0$, since the right-continuity of $X$ implies $$\operatorname P_x\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{t_n}= x\right]=1\;,$$ right? [Don't think, that I try to teach you. I'm still learning and want to make sure, that I've really understand the argumentation].

Comment: @0xbadf00d In the discrete topology $V$ should be $\{x\}$, as you noted. Sorry if that confused you. The rest of your argument is what I meant with the last couple of lines, so you understood correctly :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your Claim is correct in the generality you have stated it in.

Consider a Markov chain on the state space $E=\{1, 1/2, 1/3,\ldots\}\cup\{0\}$ with the topology it inherits as a subspace of the real line. The process $X_t$ is to be a sort of "pure birth" process: If started in state $1/n$, $X_t$ holds there for an exponential random time with mean value $n^{-2}$ and then jumps to state $1/(n-1)$ (here $n=2,3,\ldots$), etc. The state $1$ is absorbing. Starting from the state $0$ the process move (very rapidly at first!) through the non-zero states in increasing order. Think of the law $\Bbb P_0$ as the limit $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}\Bbb P_x$. The sample paths of this chain are right continuous. But  $\Bbb P_0[X_t\not=0,\forall t>0]=1$. In particular, $p_t(0,0)=0$ for all $t>0$, but $\Bbb P_x[\tau=0]=1$.

As requested by Did: Let $\xi_k$, $k=2,3,\ldots$ be independent exponential random variables, with $\Bbb E \xi_k=k^{-2}$ ($\xi_k$ represents the holding time in state $1/k$). Define $T_n=\sum_{k>n} \xi_k$. This is the time it takes $X_t$ to reach state $1/n$ if started in state $0$. We then have $p_t(0,1/n)=\Bbb P[T_n\le t]-\Bbb P[T_{n-1}\le t]$. One can easily write down an expression for the Laplace tansform $\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}p_t(0,1/n)\,dt$. I'm not sure how easy it would be to express $p_t(0,1/n)$ in a closed form expresion.

Comment: What are the transition probabilities from state 0?

Comment: I've added a formula to my Answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in phrasing the question. Actually, I've intended to let $\mathcal E$ be the discrete topology on $E$. dafinguzman provided an answer assuming that topology. What do you think about his proof? Was the topology the only reason why you've mentioned that the claim doesn't hold in general?

Comment: Right continuous in the discrete topology means that each state is a holding point, and this make your Claim clearly true.

Comment: @JohnDawkins What is a *holding point*?

Comment: When a Markov process enters a state that's a "holding point" it stays there (or "holds") for a random (exponential) period of time and then moves on, typically by jumping to another state.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Why exponential?